# Xamarin Android crashing with Xamarin.Auth

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android

I'm using Xamarin.Auth to log into Facebook. I created a separate Renderer for iOS and Android. 
In the auth.Completed I call a method AfterLogin(UserInfo) in the PCL class of the custom renderer. This does some additional work and then calls

```
App.Current.MainPage = new NavigationPage(new MainPage());
```

It looks like the page is constructed correctly and all methods return correctly until an Exception Unhandled gets thrown. The only text is "An unhandled exception occured."

In iOS, everything works fine. It calls the exact same PCL code.

I have no idea what view it is referring to.

**Edit**
Stack trace from ADB

```
  I/MonoDroid(11638): UNHANDLED EXCEPTION:

 I/MonoDroid(11638): Java.Lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x4 (unknown) for fragment FragmentContainer{436fa3e8 #0 id=0x4}

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at System.Runtime.ExceptionServices.ExceptionDispatchInfo.Throw () [0x0000c] in <d18287e1d683419a8ec3216fd78947b9>:0 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at Java.Interop.JniEnvironment+InstanceMethods.CallBooleanMethod (Java.Interop.JniObjectReference instance, Java.Interop.JniMethodInfo method) [0x00068] in <5716a943049b49ca928a3a1c8d2386f4>:0 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at Android.Runtime.JNIEnv.CallBooleanMethod (System.IntPtr jobject, System.IntPtr jmethod) [0x0000e] in <33e6e739ac344166b157e323586f11a1>:0 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at Android.Support.V4.App.FragmentManagerInvoker.ExecutePendingTransactions () [0x00033] in <7e083afc7c9045f59e01d9c14931060d>:0 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.NavigationPageRenderer.Dispose (System.Boolean disposing) [0x00083] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\NavigationPageRenderer.cs:135 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at Java.Lang.Object.Dispose () [0x00000] in <33e6e739ac344166b157e323586f11a1>:0 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.AppCompat.Platform.SetPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page newRoot) [0x0003f] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\Platform.cs:226 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.InternalSetPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page page) [0x0001a] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:370 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity.AppOnPropertyChanged (System.Object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args) [0x00012] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android\AppCompat\FormsAppCompatActivity.cs:321 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at Xamarin.Forms.BindableObject.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName) [0x0000a] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\BindableObject.cs:136 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at Xamarin.Forms.Element.OnPropertyChanged (System.String propertyName) [0x00000] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Element.cs:380 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at Xamarin.Forms.Application.set_MainPage (Xamarin.Forms.Page value) [0x0008b] in C:\BuildAgent3\work\ca3766cfc22354a1\Xamarin.Forms.Core\Application.cs:90 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at App.App.Instance_DataIsReady (System.Object sender, App.EventArguments.DataIsReadyEventArgs e) [0x0004d] in <9b95d86146df403c82b64e5a8ab6a9cf>:0 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at (wrapper delegate-invoke) <Module>:invoke_void_object_DataIsReadyEventArgs (object,App.EventArguments.DataIsReadyEventArgs)

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at App.DataCache.OnDataIsReady (App.EventArguments.DataIsReadyStates state) [0x0001b] in <9b95d86146df403c82b64e5a8ab6a9cf>:0 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at App.DataCache.set_PlayerWinnings (System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable`1[T] value) [0x00012] in <9b95d86146df403c82b64e5a8ab6a9cf>:0 

I/MonoDroid(11638):   at App.DataCache+<RefreshData>d__37.MoveNext () [0x00351] in <9b95d86146df403c82b64e5a8ab6a9cf>:0 

I/MonoDroid(11638): --- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
```

Comment: Could you update your code with the custom renderer used in the Android Project ?

Comment: Absent stack trace and MainPage constructor, your guess will be as good as anyone's.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Which version of Xamarin.Auth?
Why implementing Xamarin.Forms support if it is already in the library itself since version 1.5.0?

And for more help we'll need more info from your side (and your code)...

Answer (score 0):

The issue turned out to be that MainPage was being assigned to twice. It wasn't related to Auth.